# Need help to figure out sorting sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the total number of levels gained or lost from this sort of table:

```
id   name   level   timestamp
1    Rex      15       10:25
2    Rex      15       10:26
3    Rex      15       10:27
4    Rex      14       10:28
5    Rex      13       10:29
6    Rex      13       10:30
7    Rex      13       10:31
8    Rex      13       10:29
9    Xer      44       10:30
10   Xer      44       10:31
11   Xer      45       10:32
12   Xer      45       10:33
13   Xer      45       10:34
```

Currently I'm running

```
SELECT id, name, level, timestamp, MAX(level) - MIN(level) AS gained
FROM log
GROUP BY name
```

But the problem with this query is that both gained and lost levels will count as gained. It would be perfect if I could get a negative int in the gained column if the user has lost levels

The output I want from the data above is:

```
id   name   level   timestamp   gained
8    Rex     13       10:29      -2
13   Xer     45       10:34       1
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. (I.e. your current query is invalid and shouldn't even execute. Read about MySQL's only_full_group_by.)

Comment: Add a few more rows with sampe data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Try to group by id, name, level, timestamp

Comment: Is the answer '-2'?

Comment: I've added some sample data and specified the wanted result. Yes, the answer would be -2.

Comment: I tried grouping id, name, level and timestamp as stanley suggested but it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to respect the timeline, then try something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, name,
       ( SELECT level FROM log l0 WHERE l.name = l0.name ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ) level,
       MAX(timestamp) timestamp,
       -- last entry for the name
       ( SELECT level FROM log l1 WHERE l.name = l1.name ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ) -
       -- first entry for the name
       ( SELECT level FROM log l2 WHERE l.name = l2.name ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1 ) gained
FROM log l
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I think topic starter need difference by time. So in subqueries order should to be by timestamp.
Then it is possible get negative value.

Comment: This query doesn't differentiate between levels going up or down so it only returns positive values even if the level values has gone down. And it doesn't deliver the expected output either

Comment: You are still missing the column level in your output

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but these queries takes forever to try. This one works as I want it to. Thank you so much! Would there be any optimization to increase execution time on this query? When ordering by 'gained' DESC/ASC it takes about 30 minutes to run

Comment: Thank you so much, again. I've looked into indexing for my first time, and just adding the basic indexing on the timestamp field reduced the execution time from 30-90 minutes to 3-5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I used LAG in as subquery to get the changes and then summed those changes in an outer sub-query. To get the last row I uses yet another query to find the max time for each name. Maybe not the most efficient query but it works

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.level, l.timestamp, sg.gain
FROM log l
JOIN (SELECT name, SUM(gain) gain
      FROM (SELECT name, level - COALESCE(LAG(level) OVER w, level) as gain
            FROM log
            WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp)) as g
      GROUP BY name) as sg ON sg.name = l.name
JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(time) max_t
      FROM log
      GROUP BY name) mt ON mt.name = l.name AND mt.max_t = l.time
```